# Android get text from button

Tags: android, button, text, get

I have 6 `Buttons` on my screen

I need to check the text on each `Button` and if the result is a capital "X" then I need to make the `Button` invisible

I can get the text when a `Button` is clicked using this

```
Button b = (Button)view;
String text = b.getText().toString();
```

but how do you get it without clicking a `Button`?

Any help appreciated

mark

Comment: what do you mean by: but how do you get it without?

Comment: Are you trying to say without being clicked?

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different options. If that is the only type of `View` then you can iterate through the layout's children with something like

```
for (int i=0; i<myLL.getChildCount(); i++) // assuming you have  a LinearLayout named myLL
{
     Button btn = (Button) myLL.getChildAt(i);  // cast the View to a Button
     String text = btn.getText().toString();
     // check the text here and do what you need
}
```

Or you could put them in an `ArrayList` at the beginning then iterate through that and check the text with something like

```
ArrayList<Button> myBtns = new ArrayList<Button>();
myBtns.add(R.id.someBtnId);
// iterate through them when needed.
```

There may be easier ways with listeners and such but without more information this is the best I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate of your activity (or the onCreateView of your fragment) you need to use findViewById to get the views on your app.

Once you have the views you can query their contents and set up listeners to see when they change.

Comment: this is my on create - super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen); - cant work out the other answer above

Comment: Glad you could figure it out. You should post back your exact solution or accept someone else's answer if it helped you.